# Json response for my cakephp application

Tags: json, web-services, api, rest, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I am a newbie. As Cakephp an ORM based, Can anyone tell me how would I get the data response in json?
What steps I have to follow?
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered countless times by now...
A nice overall explanation [can he found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706237/interactive-file-processing-in-cakephp/19722297#19722297).

There are two options in Cake:

1. Cake has [JSON views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) that you can use to return data.
2. An empty layout and a view that returns JSON encoded data like:

   `echo json_encode($data)`

   Of course that data must be set prior in the Controller:

   `$dataFromDb = $this->Model->find('all');`

   `$this->set('data', $dataFromDB);`

   And you also must set `Content-Type: application/json` as a header.